# Run python method only when Save button is called in form view

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, overriding, odoo-13

I have a custom module(odoo13) in which I send data from Kafka producer whenever i save or create data from form view. i have inherited write method here but whenever some onchange or compute method is run it calls write method, so every change in record triggers Kafka producer 3 to 4 times. what can be the solution of this? write method custom logic should only trigger if save button is clicked.

here's my code

```
   def write(self, vals):
        res = super(CustomModule, self).write(vals)
        #My custom logic goes here.
        return res
```

I tried below code

```
self = self.with_context({'skip_kafka_integration': True})
        res = super(CustomModule, self).write(vals)
        if self.env.context.get('skip_kafka_integration'):
            return
        #custom logic
        return res
```

this stops all previous write method to call my Kafka logic but it also stops my logic when i want that logic to be executed

Comment: It runs to set some computed fields, like it sets age on change of Birthdate. And there are more than one onchange and compute methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own button in your (inherited) XML view:

```xml
<button type="object" name="my_write" string="My Save" />
```

...which call your own method my_write()

```py
    def my_write(self, vals):
        # add your code here
        res = super(CustomModule, self).write(vals)
        return res
```

Comment: yes, I thought to do this before but how can I add context to 'save' button from XML?

Comment: ...i have changed my post